# Unmounting SMB share folder

Tags: cifs, unmounting

I mounted a SMB share folder under /mnt/smb/ and I can access the files. When I unmount this shared folder using command:

```
umount /mnt/smb/
```

naturally I cannot list shared folder contents using command:

```
ls /mnt/smb/
```

But the problem is when I run the ls command from a PHP file on the same machine, the contents of shared SMB folder can be listed! The contents of PHP file is:

```
<?php
  $command = 'ls /mnt/smb/';
  $result = shell_exec($command);
  echo $result;
?>
```

What is my mistake. Is there any other commanf needed for completely unmount the SMB share? I also used command below but there was no luck:

```
fusermount -u /mnt/smb/
```

Comment: Please also post the output of `mount | grep /mnt/smb` after `umount`ing (when `ls` from the shell does not work), then also check whether the command gives the same result (hopefully, an empty line) after accessing from `php`.  If there is a difference maybe the share is auto-mounted again.  NB: If the output of the `mount` command contains a username or password, I suggest you remove it before posting.

Comment: The output is:
//172.16.50.207/SoftBank on /mnt/smb type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=teknik,domain=OFIS-NAS,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=172.16.50.207,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)

Comment: If that it the output **after** `umount`ing then the drive has NOT been `umount`ed in the first place! `ls /mnt/smb/` should work (at least as root!). Oh, and please move the output into your question so that it can be formatted correctly.

Comment: Sorry, my wrong. The output of mount | grep /mnt/smb after UMOUNT is empty line. My previous comment was output after MOUNT.

Comment: Very good. Now, after the empty line, (a) can you list the files by `php`?, and (b) if you can, then please test the mount command again and let us know.

Comment: @Ned64 Thank you. After running umount command a couple of times, the output become blank line. At this point, PHP file output also become blank and the problem resolved. Do you want to edit your reply before marking it as correct answer?

Comment: Also is there any way to umount all open session at once? Instead of running several umount commands?

Comment: I have edited the reply.  You can use the `umount -a` command to `umount` all mounts that are not used the moment (those will fail to umount, which is useful).  You can experiment whether all those mounts that you do need (like `/`, `/tmp`, `/sys`, `/proc`, `/dev`) are still there. Expect instability if system mounts are also umounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please repeat the `umount` command as needed, until the `/mnt/smb` folder is u(n)mounted according to `ls` in the shell.  Then it should also be according to the `mount` command:

```
mount | grep /mnt/smb
```

so that the share really is not mounted any more.  If some process still lists *remote* contents, it must be cached (unlikely in this `php` system call situation, though).

Any command can still see the *mount point*, of course, because it is a directory. Any *local* files that the directory contains will be listed, by `php` or from a shell.

In order to fix this last issue you could first move/remove the files from the local directory (while the share is **not** mounted), then do `chmod 0 /mnt/smb` as root to indicate the non-mountedness and create ls-errors while not mounted.

Comment: Thanks, any way for removing cahce?

Comment: @HamidReza Let's check whether the `umount` was successful, first.